# Где хранится профиль --headless? Или как реализовать поддержку множества профилей хрома в режиме --headless?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Для входа в аккаунты я использую профили хрома, где предварительно была осуществлена процедура логина. Это все хорошо работает, но проблема в том, что только в режиме с головой. Как только включаю headless независимо от того, какой профиль выбран запускается один и тот же профиль. Как я понимаю, браузер в режиме --headless не получает данные профиля из режима с головой, а создается отдельный профиль, но найти, где он хранится не удалось.

Comment: Данные профиля headless сохраняются по пути C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\User\Default\Local Storage\leveldb